# How do I check if a string contains another string in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, nsstring, substring

In `Objective-C` the code to check for a substring in an `NSString` is:

```
NSString *string = @"hello Swift";
NSRange textRange =[string rangeOfString:@"Swift"];
if(textRange.location != NSNotFound)
{
    NSLog(@"exists");
}
```

But how do I do this in Swift?

Comment: If you're still around, please change the accepted answer to the one by user1021430... it's correct

Comment: Swift 5+: ```if largeText.contains("stringToSearchFor") { print("yes") }```

Answer (score 1275, accepted):

You can do exactly the same call with Swift:

#### Swift 4 & Swift 5

In Swift 4 String is a collection of `Character` values, it wasn't like this in Swift 2 and 3, so you can use this more concise code<sup>1</sup>:

```
let string = "hello Swift"
if string.contains("Swift") {
    print("exists")
}
```

#### Swift 3.0+

```
var string = "hello Swift"

if string.range(of:"Swift") != nil { 
    print("exists")
}

// alternative: not case sensitive
if string.lowercased().range(of:"swift") != nil {
    print("exists")
}
```

#### Older Swift

```
var string = "hello Swift"

if string.rangeOfString("Swift") != nil{ 
    println("exists")
}

// alternative: not case sensitive
if string.lowercaseString.rangeOfString("swift") != nil {
    println("exists")
}
```

I hope this is a helpful solution since some people, including me, encountered some strange problems by calling `containsString()`.<sup>1</sup>

PS. Don't forget to `import Foundation`

#### Footnotes

1. Just remember that using collection functions on Strings has some [edge cases](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string#2905661) which can give you unexpected results, e. g. when dealing with emojis or other grapheme clusters like accented letters.

Comment: I understand Swift is in beta, the amazing thing is so many devs seem to be switching to it on the first beta release. Hopefully they are filing radars.

Comment: I get 'error: 'String' does not have a member named 'rangeOfString' in playground on beta6. EDIT: because I hadn't 'import Foundation'

Comment: Apple's documentation says: `An NSRange structure giving the location and length in the receiver of the first occurrence of aString. Returns {NSNotFound, 0} if aString is not found or is empty (@"").` So maybe just checking for `nil` won't work properly.

Comment: string.lowercaseString.rangeOfString("swift").location != NSNotFound. Please read the documentation.. you will not get a nil object back.

Comment: @TheGamingArt Yes you will. Swift round-trips the whole thing for you automagically so that if the NSRange is `{NSNotFound, 0}` it is represented for you as nil. If it is an actual range, it is represented for you as a Swift Range (optional). Cool.

Comment: This is the preferred method if you need to support iOS 7.  containsString will only work in iOS 8 (or later, presumably)

Comment: Grr. containsString is not in the docs, even as of Xcode 6.3.1.

Comment: @TheGoonie: This is not calling `NSString`'s `.rangeOfString()`. This is calling `String`'s `.rangeOfString()`, which is declared as `func rangeOfString(aString: String, options mask: NSStringCompareOptions = default, range searchRange: Range<Index>? = default, locale: NSLocale? = default) -> Range<Index>?`

Comment: Folks, I am new to learning swift.  Aside from https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ and the epub available at swift.org....   what source do you prefer for api reference?  For instance, to find the `rangeOfString` method somewhere in swift's api, how would one find and use it, instead of turning to google/sof?  Thanks!

Comment: @Cmag: The method belongs to the class NSString which is documented within [Apple's Foundation Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/)

Comment: In Swift 3, .lowercaseString has been renamed .lowercased()

Comment: In the case insensitive example, shouldn't "range(of:"swift")" also be lowercased? Like "range(of:"swift".lowercased())"? If the text was "Swift" I don't think your example would work or maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: In Swift 3 println has been renamed print

Comment: Why not just `contains`? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1414563-contains

Comment: When checking multiple values (in a filter for example) you can do it like this  `(string.range(of: "Swift") != nil)`

Comment: usigng `"someString".range(of: query, options: .caseInsensitive)` is better

Comment: Be careful. If you use this method the empty string is not contained in another string (which it is).

Comment: Got this error **Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'String.Element' (aka 'Character')**

Comment: FYI this requires `import Foundation`. This isn't built into Swift.

Comment: contains is cheking a regexp!!! bear this in mind

Answer (score 202):

### Extension way

#### Swift 4

```
extension String {
    func contains(find: String) -> Bool{
        return self.range(of: find) != nil
    }
    func containsIgnoringCase(find: String) -> Bool{
        return self.range(of: find, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
    }
}

var value = "Hello world"

print(value.contains("Hello")) // true
print(value.contains("bo"))    // false

print(value.containsIgnoringCase(find: "hello"))    // true
print(value.containsIgnoringCase(find: "Hello"))    // true
print(value.containsIgnoringCase(find: "bo"))       // false
```

---

Generally Swift 4 has [contains](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1414563-contains) method however it available from iOS 8.0+

---

#### Swift 3.1

You can write extension `contains:` and `containsIgnoringCase` for `String`

```
extension String { 

   func contains(_ find: String) -> Bool{
     return self.range(of: find) != nil
   }

   func containsIgnoringCase(_ find: String) -> Bool{
     return self.range(of: find, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil 
   }
 }
```

---

#### Older Swift version

```
extension String {

    func contains(find: String) -> Bool{
       return self.rangeOfString(find) != nil
     }

    func containsIgnoringCase(find: String) -> Bool{
       return self.rangeOfString(find, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch) != nil
     }
}
```

---

*Example:*

```
var value = "Hello world"

print(value.contains("Hello")) // true
print(value.contains("bo"))    // false

print(value.containsIgnoringCase("hello"))    // true
print(value.containsIgnoringCase("Hello"))    // true
print(value.containsIgnoringCase("bo"))       // false
```

Comment: to ignore case use return self.rangeOfString(find, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch) != nil

Comment: No longer necessary unless you don't have `Foundation` around... `containsString` works fine.

Comment: for swift 3.0. Change to below: extension String {
    func contains(find: String) -> Bool{
        return self.range(of: find) != nil
    }
    func containsIgnoringCase(find: String) -> Bool{
        return self.range(of: find, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
    }
}

Comment: For Swift 4 ->   extension String {
    
    func contains(find: String) -> Bool{
        return self.range(of: find) != nil
    }
    
    func containsIgnoringCase(find: String) -> Bool{
        return self.range(of: find, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
    }
}

Answer (score 51):

From the docs, it seems that calling `containsString()` on a String should work:

> Swift’s String type is bridged seamlessly to Foundation’s NSString
>   class. If you are working with the Foundation framework in Cocoa or
>   Cocoa Touch, the entire NSString API is available to call on any
>   String value you create, in addition to the String features described
>   in this chapter. You can also use a String value with any API that
>   requires an NSString instance.

However, it doesn't seem to work that way.

If you try to use `someString.containsString(anotherString)`, you will get a compile time error that states `'String' does not contain a member named 'containsString'`.

So, you're left with a few options, one of which is to explicitly bridge your `String` to Objective-C by using `bridgeToObjectiveC()` other two involve explicitly using an `NSString` and the final one involves casting the `String` to an `NSString`

By bridging, you'd get:

```
var string = "hello Swift"
if string.bridgeToObjectiveC().containsString("Swift") {
    println("YES")
}
```

By explicitly typing the string as an `NSString`, you'd get:

```
var string: NSString = "hello Swift"
if string.containsString("Swift") {
    println("YES")
}
```

If you have an existing `String`, you can initialize an NSString from it by using NSString(string:):

```
var string = "hello Swift"
if NSString(string: string).containsString("Swift") {
    println("YES")
}
```

And finally, you can cast an existing `String` to an `NSString` as below

```
var string = "hello Swift"
if (string as NSString).containsString("Swift") {
    println("YES")
}
```

Comment: The last example (I haven't tried others) crashes for me on iOS 7 (device); Swift apps should run just fine on iOS 7. The error I get is `[__NSCFString containsString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`. Also, I can't find the method `containsString` in the dev docs to confirm if its new for iOS 8.

Comment: Interesting. I only tested this on a playground. I will give it a try later when I'm on my computer.

Comment: the third and fourth options are the only ones the compiler allowed. both crash for me in beta 4 in iOS 7.

Answer (score 41):

Another one. Supports case and diacritic options.

Swift 3.0

```
struct MyString {
  static func contains(_ text: String, substring: String,
                       ignoreCase: Bool = true,
                       ignoreDiacritic: Bool = true) -> Bool {

    var options = NSString.CompareOptions()

    if ignoreCase { _ = options.insert(NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive) }
    if ignoreDiacritic { _ = options.insert(NSString.CompareOptions.diacriticInsensitive) }

    return text.range(of: substring, options: options) != nil
  }
}
```

### Usage

```
MyString.contains("Niels Bohr", substring: "Bohr") // true
```

### iOS 9+

Case and diacritic insensitive function available since iOS 9.

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
  "Für Elise".localizedStandardContains("fur") // true
}
```

Answer (score 31):

As of Xcode 7.1 and Swift 2.1 `containsString()` is working fine for me.

```
let string = "hello swift"
if string.containsString("swift") {
    print("found swift")
}
```

Swift 4:

```
let string = "hello swift"
if string.contains("swift") {
    print("found swift")
}
```

And a case insensitive Swift 4 example:

```
let string = "Hello Swift"
if string.lowercased().contains("swift") {
    print("found swift")
}
```

Or using a case insensitive `String` extension:

```
extension String {
    func containsIgnoreCase(_ string: String) -> Bool {
        return self.lowercased().contains(string.lowercased())
    }
}

let string = "Hello Swift"
let stringToFind = "SWIFT"
if string.containsIgnoreCase(stringToFind) {
    print("found: \(stringToFind)")  // found: SWIFT
}
print("string: \(string)")
print("stringToFind: \(stringToFind)")

// console output:
found: SWIFT
string: Hello Swift
stringToFind: SWIFT
```

Comment: you need to `import Foundation`, otherwise this won't work.

Comment: Either `import UIKit` of `import Foundation` is required, at least with iOS 11 and Swift 4.

Comment: But that is case sensitive. How do you do comparison while ignoring case . Like in java String.equalsIgnoreCase(anotherString) ?

Comment: @zulkarnainshah I added an example to the answer.

Comment: @MurraySagal Thats still not case insensitive search. You're converting the original string to lowercase and then comparing that explicitly with a lower case string. It will do the job, but thats not the ideal way to do that

Comment: @zulkarnainshah I added another example showing that original values are not changed. I imagine that's pretty much how java's `equalsIgnoreCase()` or `containsIgnoreCase() is implemented.

Answer (score 23):

### In Swift 4.2

Use

```
func contains(_ str: String) -> Bool
```

### Example

```
let string = "hello Swift"
let containsSwift = string.contains("Swift")
print(containsSwift) // prints true
```

Comment: Please note that this requires that you import Foundation.

Answer (score 16):

**> IN SWIFT 3.0**

```
let str = "Hello Swift"
if str.lowercased().contains("Swift".lowercased()) {
    print("String Contains Another String")
} else {
    print("Not Exists")
}
```

***Output***

```
String Contains Another String
```

Answer (score 15):

You can do this very easily in Swift using the code:

```
let string = "hello Swift";
let subString = (string as NSString).containsString("Swift")
if(subString){println("Exist")}
```

Answer (score 10):

Just an addendum to the answers here.

You can also do a local case insensitive test using:

```
 - (BOOL)localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString:(NSString *)aString
```

Example:

```
    import Foundation

    var string: NSString  =  "hello Swift"
   if string.localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString("Hello") {
    println("TRUE")
}
```

**UPDATE**

This is part of the Foundation Framework for iOS & **Mac OS X 10.10.x**
 and was part of 10.10 at Time of my original Posting.

> Document Generated: 2014-06-05 12:26:27 -0700 OS X Release Notes
>   Copyright © 2014 Apple Inc. All Rights Reserved.
>
> [OS X 10.10 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-Foundation/#10_10StringEncodingDetection) Cocoa Foundation Framework
>
> NSString now has the following two convenience methods:
>
> `- (BOOL)containsString:(NSString *)str;`
>
> `- (BOOL)localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString:(NSString *)str;`

Comment: Be aware this approach requires iOS 8.

Answer (score 10):

Of all of the answers here, I think they either don't work, or they're a bit of a hack (casting back to NSString).  It's very likely that the correct answer to this has changed with the different beta releases.

Here is what I use:

```
let string: String = "hello Swift"
if string.rangeOfString("Swift") != nil
{
    println("exists")
}
```

The "!= nil" became required with Beta 5.

Answer (score 9):

You can just do what you have mentioned:

```
import Foundation
...
string.contains("Swift");
```

From the docs:

> Swift’s `String` type is bridged seamlessly to Foundation’s `NSString`
>   class. If you are working with the Foundation framework in Cocoa or
>   Cocoa Touch, the entire `NSString` API is available to call on any
>   `String` value you create, in addition to the String features described
>   in this chapter. You can also use a String value with any API that
>   requires an NSString instance.

You need to `import Foundation` to bridge the `NSString` methods and make them available to Swift's String class.

Comment: Not me, but no, it doesn't.

Comment: yep. Tried in a Playground, in a Mac App and in an iOS app. Also tried in Playground importing Cocoa, UIKit, Foundation and all possible combinations of the three of them (except Cocoa/UIKit, which doesn't make sense)

Comment: This is no longer the case as of Swift 1.2

Answer (score 9):

Here is my first stab at this in the swift playground.
I extend String by providing two new functions (contains and containsIgnoreCase)

```
extension String {
    func contains(other: String) -> Bool{
        var start = startIndex

        do{
            var subString = self[Range(start: start++, end: endIndex)]
            if subString.hasPrefix(other){
                return true
            }

        }while start != endIndex

        return false
    }

    func containsIgnoreCase(other: String) -> Bool{
        var start = startIndex

        do{
            var subString = self[Range(start: start++, end: endIndex)].lowercaseString
            if subString.hasPrefix(other.lowercaseString){
                return true
            }

        }while start != endIndex

        return false
    }
}
```

Use it like this

```
var sentence = "This is a test sentence"
sentence.contains("this")  //returns false
sentence.contains("This")  //returns true
sentence.containsIgnoreCase("this")  //returns true

"This is another test sentence".contains(" test ")    //returns true
```

I'd welcome any feedback :)

Comment: Next step: Make this a generic function which works on all Collection's :-) E.g. checkout the startsWith() builtin function. In the 'ignore case' variant, only lowercase the strings once (let lc = other.lowercaseString before the do)

Answer (score 7):

Swift 5, case insensitive:

```
if string.localizedLowercase.contains("swift".localizedLowercase){
    // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here you are:

```
let s = "hello Swift"
if let textRange = s.rangeOfString("Swift") {
    NSLog("exists")
}
```

Comment: Sometime you might need a compact form as follows:

    let rangeIfExists = string.rangeOfString("Swift") ?? false

which either returns false as a boolean if it's not contained or the NSRange otherwise

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to write any custom code for this. Starting from the 1.2 version Swift has already had all the methods you need:

- getting string length: `count(string)`;
- checking if string contains substring: `contains(string, substring)`;
- checking if string starts with substring: `startsWith(string, substring)`
- and etc.

Comment: Swift 2 is not the same.

Comment: **Swift 2**: string.hasPrefix(“start”)

Answer (score 5):

In Swift 3

```
if((a.range(of: b!, options: String.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil)) != nil){
    print("Done")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here you go! Ready for Xcode 8 and Swift 3.

```
import UIKit

let mString = "This is a String that contains something to search."
let stringToSearchUpperCase = "String"
let stringToSearchLowerCase = "string"

mString.contains(stringToSearchUpperCase) //true
mString.contains(stringToSearchLowerCase) //false
mString.lowercased().contains(stringToSearchUpperCase) //false
mString.lowercased().contains(stringToSearchLowerCase) //true
```

Answer (score 3):

string.containsString is only available in 10.10 Yosemite (and probably iOS8).
Also bridging it to ObjectiveC crashes in 10.9. You're trying to pass a NSString to NSCFString. I don't know the difference, but I can say 10.9 barfs when it executes this code in a OS X 10.9 app.

Here are the differences in Swift with 10.9 and 10.10:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/General/Reference/APIDiffsMacOSX10_10SeedDiff/index.html containsString is only available in 10.10

Range of String above works great on 10.9.  I am finding developing on 10.9 is super stable with Xcode beta2.  I don't use playgrounds through or the command line version of playgrounds. I'm finding if the proper frameworks are imported the autocomplete is very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Xcode 8/Swift 3 version:

```
let string = "hello Swift"

if let range = string.range(of: "Swift") {
    print("exists at range \(range)")
} else {
    print("does not exist")
}

if let lowercaseRange = string.lowercased().range(of: "swift") {
    print("exists at range \(lowercaseRange)")
} else {
    print("does not exist")
}
```

You can also use `contains`:

```
string.contains("swift") // false
string.contains("Swift") // true
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4** way to check for substrings, including the necessary `Foundation` (or `UIKit`) framework import:

```
import Foundation // or UIKit

let str = "Oh Canada!"

str.contains("Can") // returns true

str.contains("can") // returns false

str.lowercased().contains("can") // case-insensitive, returns true
```

Unless `Foundation` (or `UIKit`) framework is imported, `str.contains("Can")` will give a compiler error.

---

This answer is regurgitating [manojlds's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24034239/1233251), which is completely correct. I have no idea why so many answers go through so much trouble to recreate `Foundation`'s `String.contains(subString: String)` method.

Answer (score 3):

With and new syntax in swift 4 you can just

`string.contains("Swift 4 is the best")`

string is your string variable

Answer (score 2):

Check if it contains 'Hello'

```
let s = "Hello World"

if s.rangeOfString("Hello") != nil {
    print("Yes it contains 'Hello'")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check that one String contains another Sub-String within it or not you can check it like this too,

```
var name = String()  
name = "John has two apples."
```

Now, in this particular string if you want to know if it contains fruit name 'apple' or not you can do,

```
if name.contains("apple") {  
  print("Yes , it contains fruit name")    
} else {    
  print("it does not contain any fruit name")    
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Search string exist in employee name finding.
var empName:NSString! = employeeDetails[filterKeyString] as NSString

Case sensitve search.
let rangeOfSearchString:NSRange! = empName.rangeOfString(searchString, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)

// Not found.
if rangeOfSearchString.location != Foundation.NSNotFound
{
    // search string not found in employee name.
}
// Found
else
{
    // search string found in employee name.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SWIFT 4 is very easy!!

```
if (yourString.contains("anyThing")) {
   print("Exist")
}
```

Comment: How is this any different to several of the other answers here?

Comment: `$ swift

Welcome to Apple Swift version 4.2 (swiftlang-1000.11.37.1 clang-1000.11.45.1). Type :help for assistance.

  1> print ("Ping")
Ping
  2> Print ("Ping")
error: repl.swift:2:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'Print'
Print ("Ping")
^~~~~
`
By providing an untested answer that does't work. Print != print.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 8 and newer, you can use these two `NSString` methods:

```
@availability(iOS, introduced=8.0)
func containsString(aString: String) -> Bool

@availability(iOS, introduced=8.0)
func localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(aString: String) -> Bool
```

Comment: What? it looks like it is not available? in the version that comes with xcode 6.1

Answer (score 0):

I've found a couple of interesting use cases. These variants make use of the rangeOfString method and I include the equality example to show how one might best use the search and comparison features of Strings in Swift 2.0

```
//In viewDidLoad() I assign the current object description (A Swift String) to self.loadedObjectDescription
self.loadedObjectDescription = self.myObject!.description
```

> Later after I've made changes to self.myObject, I can refer to the
>   following string comparison routines (setup as lazy variables that
>   return a Bool). This allows one to check the state at any time.

```
lazy var objectHasChanges : Bool = {
        guard self.myObject != nil else { return false }
        return !(self.loadedObjectDescription == self.myObject!.description)
    }()
```

> A variant of this happens when sometimes I need to analyze a missing
>   property on that object. A string search allows me to find a
>   particular substring being set to nil (the default when an object is created).

```
    lazy var isMissingProperty : Bool = {
        guard self.myObject != nil else { return true }
        let emptyPropertyValue = "myProperty = nil"
        return (self.myObject!.description.rangeOfString(emptyPropertyValue) != nil) ? true : false
    }()
```