# Swift String in String

Tags: string, swift, nsstring

Before Beta 5 I could use

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
str.bridgeToObjectiveC().containsString("Hello")
```

But this is not longer supported, is there a nice workaround for this, or does Swift already offer it now?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check if a string contains another string in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034043/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift is it called `rangeOfString`

```
"hello".rangeOfString("ell")
```

returns a range

> {Some "1..<4"}

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
var str = "Hello, playground"

if str.rangeOfString("Hello") != nil {
    println("exists")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just cast it explicitly to `NSString`:

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
(str as NSString).containsString("Hello")
```

However if there's a pure swift way to do that, I would use it - it's always better to avoid bridging unless really needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can write extension `contains:`

```
extension String {

    func contains(find: String) -> Bool{
       if let temp = self.rangeOfString(find){
          return true
       }
       return false
     }
}
```

---

*Example:*

```
var value = "Hello world"

println(value.contains("Hello")) // true
println(value.contains("bo"))    // false
```

Comment: Thanks the example 2 is the best way i think :)!