# Swift: String contains String (Without using NSString)?

Tags: string, swift

I have the same problem like in this question:

[How do I check if a string contains another string in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034043/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-swift)

But now a few months later I wonder if it can be done without using NSString?
I nice and simple contains-method would be fine.
I searched the web and the documentation but I found nothing!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a string contains another string in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034043/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-swift)

Answer (score 28):

Same way, just with Swift syntax:

```
let string = "This is a test.  This is only a test"

if string.rangeOfString("only") != nil {
     println("yes")
}
```

For Swift 3.0

```
if str.range(of: "abc") != nil{
     print("Got the string")
}
```

Comment: what about "is", can i get the last "is"?

Comment: @Zam In that case, it will returns the first coincidence/match for `is`, and if you print the `range` you will get something like `2..<4` {^_^} --> `if let range = string.rangeOfString("is") { print(range) }`

Comment: Is that syntax still used in Swift 2 ?

Comment: `rangeOfString` is an `NSString` method.

Comment: @mxcl CMD+Click the method in Xcode und you will see that Swift's String has an own implementation of rangeOfString.
Testing for != nil wouldn't work with the NSString implementation btw.

Comment: @Thyraz it's not: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/String.swift

Comment: Nice and simple. I like it.

Comment: Please use consistent examples for Swift2/Swift3. And mention that `range(of:)` is part of `Foundation`, so you need to import that.

Answer (score 2):

`String` actually provides a "contains" function through `StringProtocol`.
No extension whatsoever needed:

```
let str = "asdf"
print(str.contains("sd") ? "yep" : "nope")
```

[image]

<strike>https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string</strike>
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol

---

If you want to check if your string matches a specific pattern, I can recommend the NSHipster article about NSRegularExpressions: http://nshipster.com/nsregularexpression/

Comment: That's check if the string contains а certain character!

Comment: @EmilMarashliev That is true. But additionally you can check anything that conforms to the `StringProtocol` - so it also works for `String`.

Comment: Ha, you're completely right it comes from `StringProtocol`   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/stringprotocol/2923423-contains it's more convenient and elegant way than `range(of:)`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an extension on String for SWIFT 3.0  so that i could simply call `absoluteString.contains(string: "/kredit/")`

```
extension String {
  public func contains(string: String)-> Bool {
      return self.rangeOfString(string) != nil
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

just to demonstrate the use of options.

```
var string = "This is a test.  This is only a test. Not an Exam"

if string.range(of:"ex") != nil {
    print("yes")
}
if string.range(of:"ex", options: String.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive) != nil {
    print("yes")
}
```