# How do I check if a String includes a specific Character?

Tags: string, swift, character

How do I check if a `String` includes a specific `Character`?

For example:

```
if !emailString.hasCharacter("@") {
    println("Email must contain at sign.")
}
```

Comment: Note, not a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25957594/3925941) since that is checking if a string contains another string, not a character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [free-standing `find` function](https://developer.apple.com/library//ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Algorithms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014608-CH15-SW1), like this:

```
let s = "hello"
if (find(s, "x") != nil) {
    println("Found X")
}
if (find(s, "l") != nil) {
    println("Found L")
}
```

Comment: Note for anyone upgrading to Swift 2, this would now be `if s.characters.indexOf("x") != nil { }` (as `find` was renamed to `indexOf` and is now a protocol extension on `CollectionType`, while `String` no longer is and instead has a `characters` collection property)

Comment: Now in Swift 4 it is: s.index(of: "x") != nil

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
if emailString.rangeOfString("@") != nil{
    println("@ exists")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
if emailString.rangeOfString("@") == nil {
        println("Email must contain at sign.")
}
```