# What is the best way to determine if a string contains a character from a set in Swift

Tags: swift

I need to determine if a string contains any of the characters from a custom set that I have defined.

I see from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034043/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-swift) post that you can use rangeOfString to determine if a string contains another string. This, of course, also works for characters if you test each character one at a time.

I'm wondering what the best way to do this is.

Comment: Do you want to check if a string is empty or not?

Comment: @CeceXX no, I have a custom set of characters I would like to check against.

Comment: @mattnedrich: Why don't you add that information to the question itself? Both the question contents and the title sound as if you are looking for a *single character* (which might be the reason for the down-vote).

Comment: @MartinR thanks for the feedback, I've updated the question and the title

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can create a `CharacterSet` containing the set of your custom characters
and then test the membership against this character set:

**Swift 3:**

```
let charset = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "aw")
if str.rangeOfCharacter(from: charset) != nil {
    print("yes")
}
```

For case-insensitive comparison, use

```
if str.lowercased().rangeOfCharacter(from: charset) != nil {
    print("yes")
}
```

(assuming that the character set contains only lowercase letters).

**Swift 2:**

```
let charset = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "aw")
if str.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(charset) != nil {
    print("yes")
}
```

**Swift 1.2**

```
let charset = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "aw")
if str.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(charset, options: nil, range: nil) != nil {
    println("yes")
}
```

Comment: Why lowercase?  It could be that the custom character set specifically excludes some or all lowercase characters.  Also, CharacterSet conforms to the SetAlgebra protocol; CharacterSet.isDisjoint() could be used to determine if the custom CharacterSet has any members in common with the input string (as per Chris Hatton's answer below, but with CharacterSets instead of Sets.)

Comment: @Matt: I do not remember why I added the lowercase conversion, perhaps as an option or because it is used in the Q&A which is referenced in the question. I have tried to clarify that now. – And yes, you could write `if !charset.isDisjoint(with: CharacterSet(charactersIn: str))`. Is that what you meant? Not sure if it is simpler or more efficient.

Comment: @MartinR Do you know why `rangeOfCharacter(from: charset, options: .caseInsensitive)` doesn't work?

Comment: @LeoDabus: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1416898-rangeofcharacter specifies  "anchored" and "backwards" as the only possible options. The technical reason might be that a CharacterSet is internally just a large bitmap (for efficiency).

Answer (score 23):

**ONE LINE Swift4** solution to check if contains letters:

```
CharacterSet.letters.isSuperset(of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: myString) // returns BOOL
```

Another case when you need to **validate string for custom char sets**. For example if string contains **only** letters and (for example) dashes and spaces:

```
let customSet: CharacterSet = [" ", "-"]
let finalSet = CharacterSet.letters.union(customSet)
finalSet.isSuperset(of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: myString)) // BOOL
```

Hope it helps someone one day:)

Answer (score 9):

Swift 3 example:

```
extension String{
    var isContainsLetters : Bool{
        let letters = CharacterSet.letters
        return self.rangeOfCharacter(from: letters) != nil
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
"123".isContainsLetters // false
```

Answer (score 7):

From Swift 1.2 you can do that using `Set`

```
var str = "Hello, World!"
let charset: Set<Character> = ["e", "n"]

charset.isSubsetOf(str)     // `true` if `str` contains all characters in `charset`
charset.isDisjointWith(str) // `true` if `str` does not contains any characters in `charset`
charset.intersect(str)      // set of characters both `str` and `charset` contains.
```

**Swift 3 or later**

```
let isSubset = charset.isSubset(of: str)        // `true` if `str` contains all characters in `charset`
let isDisjoint = charset.isDisjoint(with: str)  // `true` if `str` does not contains any characters in `charset`
let intersection = charset.intersection(str)    // set of characters both `str` and `charset` contains.
print(intersection.count)   // 1
```

Comment: In Swift 2.0, `str` should be `str.characters`

Comment: Time to remove Swift 1.2 method?

Comment: `Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'CharacterSet'`

Answer (score 4):

**swift3**

```
var str = "Hello, playground"
let res = str.characters.contains { ["x", "z"].contains( $0 ) }
```

Answer (score 3):

Using **Swift 3** to determine if your string contains characters from a **specific CharacterSet**:

```
    let letters = CharacterSet.alphanumerics
    let string = "my-string_"
    if (string.trimmingCharacters(in: letters) != "") {
        print("Invalid characters in string.")
    }
    else {
        print("Only letters and numbers.")
    }
```

Comment: For a real Swift 3 answer, you should use `CharacterSet` instead of `NSCharacterSet`.

Comment: This isn't going to test whether the string "contains" the characters in the set. It only tests whether the ends of the string have characters in that set. Internal characters are ignored.

Answer (score 2):

```
func isAnyCharacter( from charSetString: String, containedIn string: String ) -> Bool
{
    return Set( charSetString.characters ).isDisjointWith( Set( string.characters) ) == false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4

```
let myString = "Some Words"

if myString.contains("Some"){
    print("myString contains the word `Some`")
}else{
    print("myString does NOT contain the word `Some`")
}
```

Swift 3:

```
let myString = "Some Words"

if (myString.range(of: "Some") != nil){
    print("myString contains the word `Some`")
}else{
    print("Word does not contain `Some`")
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  OP asks for "any of the characters from a custom set".

Answer (score 1):

## Updated for Swift 5.1

Question was specifically: "if a string contains any of the characters from a custom set" and not checking for all characters in the custom set.

Using

```swift
func check(in string: String, forAnyIn characters: String) -> Bool {
    // create one character set
    let customSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: characters)
    // use the rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet) function
    return string.rangeOfCharacter(from: customSet) != nil 
}

check(in: "abc", forAnyIn: "A") // false
check(in: "abc", forAnyIn: "b") // true
```

But this is also very easy to check using character sets.

```swift
func check(in string: String, forAnyIn characters: String) -> Bool {
    let customSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: characters)
    let inputSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
    return !inputSet.intersection(customSet).isEmpty
}

check(in: "abc", forAnyIn: "A") // false
check(in: "abc", forAnyIn: "b") // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way:

```
var string = "Hello, World!"

if string.rangeOfString("W") != nil {
     println("exists")
} else {
     println("doesn't exist")
}

// alternative: not case sensitive
if string.lowercaseString.rangeOfString("w") != nil {
     println("exists")
} else {
     println("doesn't exist")
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP asks for "any of the characters from a custom set".

Answer (score -1):

Use like this in swift 4.2

```
    var string = "Hello, World!"
    let charSet = NSCharacterSet.letters
    if string.rangeOfCharacter(from:charSet)?.isEmpty == false{  
      print ("String contain letters");
    }
```

Comment: `?.isEmpty == false` is pointlessly complicated.  Use `!= nil`.