# Find 1 of 3 characters in a string

Tags: string, swift3

I have to find 1 of 3 characters in a string. How can I do that?

I tried this:

```
let value = "from 3,95 €"
let wanted: Character = "£", "€" OR "₹"
if let idx = value.characters.index(of: wanted) {                                    
    print("Found \(wanted)")
} else {
    print("Not found")
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You just want to check String having that character or not, right or you want index of that character also ?

Comment: Any reason for why you don't use `NSNumberFormatter`? Check this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter).

Comment: @Nirav D: Yes, i just want to check if one of these characters in a string or not. No i don't need the index....

Comment: @Saintz see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44623471/3687801) below

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to determine if a string contains a character from a set in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486138/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-if-a-string-contains-a-character-from-a-set-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't exactly know what you want achieve but if you want to know which character string contains from these 3 character then you can make something like this.

```
let value = "from 3,95 €"
let wanted: [Character] = ["£", "€", "₹"]
if let result = value.characters.first(where: { wanted.contains($0) }) {
    print("Found \(result)")
} else {
    print("Not found")
}
```

**Output**

```
Found €
```

**Edit:** If you just want to check the string contains then use `contains(where:)` instead of `first(where:)`

```
if value.characters.contains(where: { wanted.contains($0) }) {
    print("Found")
} else {
    print("Not found")
}
```

Comment: I just want to check if one of these characters in a string or not. No i don't need the index....

Comment: contains(where:) won't help: They say : Fix it : delete "where:"

Comment: @Saintz Both the code perfectly compiling and running on my side can you show what you are trying, also check once again that you are trying exactly same code that I have added

Comment: @Saintz Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3:**

```
if let dataArray = value.characters.filter{ $0 == "£" || $0 == "€" || $0 == "₹" }, dataArray.count > 0 {
//you have at least one of them in your string, so do whatever you want here
}
```

Comment: Sorry, one more question. And if i want to find no one of these characters in the string is it ??? :
!value.characters.filter{ $0 == "£" || $0 == "€" || $0 == "₹" }, dataArray.count > 0 {...

Comment: you can use ```else {}``` statement. 
```if let dataArray = ... > 0 {} else {//None of them found}```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to just determine whether they exists or not:

```
let value = "from 3,95 €"
let wanted = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "£€₹")
if value.rangeOfCharacter(from: wanted) != nil {
    print("Found")
} else {
    print("Not found")
}
```