# Swift 4: Using Swift.contains to check existence of a Character in a String

Tags: swift

I would like to check whether a String contains any of the characters 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o' or 'u'.

I understand that the code to write it is:

```
let target : String = "monocle"
let ok : Bool = target.contains {"aeiou".contains($0)}
// more codes to use the Boolean value of variable 'ok'
```

Can anyone explain what actually goes on in the second line of the code, i.e. the initialization of the variable `ok` ?

*Edit: To be more specific, I was hoping to find out what actually goes on inside the closure. Thanks to the answer from **Sweeper**, I now understand that it means checking the String `target`, character by character (using shorthand argument name `$0`), for any of the characters 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o' or 'u'.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to determine if a string contains a character from a set in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486138/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-if-a-string-contains-a-character-from-a-set-in)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to understand the concept of "passing a closure to a method" because that is exactly what is happening in the second line.

`String.contains` can accept a closure of the type `Character -> Bool`. It will apply the closure on each character of the string and see what it returns. If the closure, when applied to any of the characters, returns `true`, then `contains` returns `true`. Otherwise, `false`.

This is the closure you are passing in:

```
{"aeiou".contains($0)}
```

`$0` means the first argument. It checks if the character passed in is one of `aeiou`. So imagine this closure gets applied to each character in the string to test, and when that returns `true`, `contains` returns `true`.

Comment: Also, wrapping in closure and using `$0` is not really necessary here. `target.contains("aeiou".contains)` will work too.