# How to check if a string contains only allowed characters in Swift

Tags: swift, string, contains

I've searched a way to check in Swift if a string contains particular characters and just them. For exemple, if a string contains them but it contains other characters as well, it should return `false`.

What I need is something which allows me to say if a string contains JUST some elements. For exemple: If I wanna know if `"101010010101"` contains ONLY 1 and 0 it should return `true`. But `"1901919117"` doesn't contains ONLY 1 and 0 it should return `false`.

Comment: Hi, please take a look [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As far from Your problem, I suggest You to first try some search on SO. I am quite sure You will find an answer that already answers this question.

Comment: I already searched but didn't find...

Comment: Ok, well, Your question is a bit unclear, at least You can add an example of possible input(s)/output(s). Maybe You could use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59823657/3402095)

Comment: `"abc".contains(where: "123".contains)` would return false `"abc1".contains(where: "123".contains)` would return true

Comment: But what I'm searching for is something which permit me to say if sth contain JUST some elements. For exemple : \
If i wanna know if 101010010101 contains JUST 1 and 0 it's true \
But 1901919117 doesn't contain JUST 1 and 0

Comment: @GhalySekkat `"101010010101".allSatisfy("01".contains)` // true or use a Set of characters as suggested by @Whirlwind

Answer (score 4):

Maybe You could go with something like this (just check if Your allowed characters are super set of Your string):

```
import Foundation

let allowedChars = Set("10")

print(allowedChars)

let a = "101010010101"
let b = "1901919117"

print(allowedChars.isSuperset(of: a)) //prints true

print(allowedChars.isSuperset(of: b)) //prints false
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's perfect !!!!!