# Swift, how can I check a string for the presence of characters from the list in it?

Tags: swift, string

I have a string string and I need to determine if one of the characters from the Correct List string is in it ?
How do I do this?

Maybe you need to change the Correct List type from String to List ?

```
import SwiftUI

struct test: View {
    var string: String = ""
    var correctList: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        Text(string)
    }
}
```

---

```
struct test_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        test(string: "Qwerty1", correctList: "1234567890")
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to determine if a string contains a character from a set in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486138/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-if-a-string-contains-a-character-from-a-set-in)

Comment: `string.contains(where: ("0"..."9").contains)`

Answer (score 0):

You can check against an arbitrary set of characters

```
let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "1234567890")
let isValid = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterSet) != nil
```

or with Regular Expression, the set of characters must be wrapped in square brackets.

```
let string = "Qwerty1"
let containsNumber = string.range(of: "[1234567890]", options: .regularExpression) != nil
```

Comment: Better to use a set of characters. Btw isNumber will return true for fractions as well