# Swift need array to be ordered by 2 properties , one containing a comma

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

So I am needing to sort my array based on 2 different sort values. I have that much down. My issue is one of my sort values is throwing me off because of the names.

Here is a sample of my data

```
{
   "name": "Battle ribbon, micro-edge"
   "level": 8
 },
 {
   "name": "Battle ribbon, traditional",
   "level": 3
 },
 {
   "name": "Battle ribbon, zero-edge",
   "level": 12
 },
 {
   "name": "Battleaxe, tactical",
   "level": 5
 },
 {
   "name": "Battleglove, cestus",
   "level": 1
 }
```

The json has been edited for this purpose. I cut out a lot of data that isn't needed for this issue.

I want to sort my data by name and by level. I want all the data to be in alphabetical order but if the names are the same to be in numerical order.

I want the following sample to be ordered like:
Battle ribbon, traditional; Battle ribbon, micro-edge; Battle ribbon, zero-edge; Battleaxe, tactical; Battleglove, cestus

The problem I am running into with:

```
return $0.name == $1.name ? $0.level < $1.level : $0.name < $1.name
```

Is it compares the full name so it outputs
Battle ribbon, micro-edge; Battle ribbon, traditional; Battle ribbon, zero-edge; Battleaxe, tactical; Battleglove, cestus

I know that most (not all names) follow this structure. I want everything before the comma sorted and anything after a comma is ignored. Some names don't contain a comma.

Any guidance would be nice.

Comment: Check out how to get the characters before the comma [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29421928/14351818)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract everything before the comma using `prefix(while:)`

Here is an example as an extension to String

```
extension String {
    var beforeComma: String {
         String(self.prefix(while: { $0 != "," }))
    }
}
```

Then your sorting would be

```
 $0.name.beforeComma < $1.name.beforeComma
```

Here is a solution that only performs the parsing once per object for better performance as suggested by @DuncanC

First map the array (values) into an array of tuples with the parsed name and the object

```
let temp = values.map { (key: $0.name.beforeComma, object: $0) }
```

Then sort the array using the tuple and map it back to the original format

```
let result = temp
    .sorted { $0.key == $1.key ? $0.object.level < $1.object.level : $0.key < $1.key }
    .map { $0.object }
```

Comment: While this would work, it would cause the string parsing to take place for every comparison in the array to be sorted. It would therefore have exponential time performance (something like `O(n²)`). For large arrays it would be VERY slow.

Comment: That’s true, I guess one could map the array to an array of tuples with the parsed string and the object for better performance but a higher memory footprint

Comment: Yup. The memory footprint would only be about 2X, but the speed increase would be dramatic. I banged out code that did exactly what you describe (build array of tuples containing string prefixes and the original objects, sort them, and then extract the sorted objects.)

Comment: Just for this bit I will have about 1100 different objects. Each with 9-15 different properties. I was thinking similar. Basically I would split the string by the comma. I was going to use a second array with all of the split strings. But was a bit lost from there and was like crap.

Comment: Thank you. That helped so much. Now I can play with all that and expand for other uses.

Comment: I just ran a test, and with a release build running on my Mac (not an iOS device) to sort a million items that contain strings that have a comma after about 32 characters, sorting by first creating tuples with the split strings is about 46 times faster than sorting where you build the split strings inside the `sorted(by:)` method. (≈2 seconds vs ≈93 seconds - a big difference)

Comment: For only 1100 items, the tuple-based method is about 34 times faster, but the total sort time for the slower method is still about 1/20th of a second. For datasets that small you probably won't notice the speed increase you get from splitting the strings before sorting them. 34 times faster sounds impressive, but you'd be hard-pressed to tell the difference between 1/20th of a second and 1/1000th of a second