# Finding if a string contains a string in Swift 2.1

Tags: string, swift

The answer in this question: [How do I check if a string contains another string in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034043/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-swift)

No longer works.

```
var string = "hello Swift"

if string.rangeOfString("Swift") != nil{
    println("exists")
}
```

Will get you:

```
error: value of type 'String' has no member 'rangeOfString'
```

What is the new way to do this?

Comment: Seems to me that you are using Swift 1.2 not 2.1. Just update your Xcode to the latest version  https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12

Comment: println it is not Xcode 7.0.1

Comment: The code snippet is to indicate the old answer no longer works, plus you will reach an error before println ever executes

Comment: the code works fine for me here Xcode 7.0.1. Exempt println() :)

Comment: The accepted answer to the linked question explicitly mentions: *"PS. Don't forget to import Foundation"*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Import Foundation and you will be able to call `rangeOfString`.

Comment: indeed I was working in Playground, and could not get the rangeOfString method to work initially, but after I imported Foundation all went smooth.