# Swift 2.2 - Value of type 'String' has no member 'contains'

Tags: swift

I am using swift 2.2 and getting the error Value of type 'String' has no member 'contains', where as the same works in swift 2.1. Can anyone please help if contains method is deprecated or removed in swift 2.2.

code

```
var another = "Test"
another.contains("we")
```

error :

> Value of type 'String' has no member 'contains'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034043/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
another.containsString("we")
```

You'll have use:

```
import Foundation
```

in your code for `containsString`

Comment: IIRC `import Cocoa` already imports `Foundation` so you don't need to add that.