# Checking if a string contains a text in a textfield

Tags: swift, string, textfield

How can I check if a `String` (for example `"apple"`) contains text that I typed in a `UITextField` (for example `"p"` or `"pp"`).
If the `String` contains the `UITextField`'s `text`, I want to print a message - for example: `"apple contains pp"`.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034043/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that like so

```
class youClass: NSObject {
  var yourTextFieldName = UITextField()

   func someMethod() {
     var apple = "apple"
     if apple.containsString(self.yourTextfieldName.text!) {
        print("apple contains \(self.yourTextfieldName.text!)")
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help, @NoNameL. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You could extend `String`:

```
extension String {
  @discardableResult
  func containsText(of textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // Precondition
    guard let text = textField.text else { return false }

    let isContained = self.contains(text)
    if isContained { print("\(self) contains \(text)") }
    return isContained
  }
}
```

Instead of just printing a result, it also returns a `Bool` indicating whether or not the `textField`'s `text` was contained in the `String`. The `@discardableResult` attribute allows you to ignore the return value if you want to though, without generating a compiler warning.

You could also take a reversed approach, by extending `UITextField`:

```
extension UITextField {
  @discardableResult
  func textIsContained(in target: String) -> Bool {
    // Precondition
    guard let text = self.text else { return false }

    let isContained = target.contains(text)
    if isContained { print("\(target) contains \(text)") }
    return isContained
  }
}
```

---

You would use these methods as follows:

```
// Your `UITextField`
let textField = UITextField()
textField.text = "pp"

// String extension:
"apple".containsText(of: textField) // returns `true` and prints "apple contains pp"

// UITextField extension:
textField.textIsContained(in: "apple") // returns `true` and prints "apple contains pp"
```