# How To Check A Username For Profanity Against A FireBase Data Snapshot

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Do not mark as duplicate, edit of this post has set it apart from the other possible duplicate post.**
I'm in the process of registering users into my application. It is essential that I disallow as many vulgar usernames as possible as they can be seen by everybody. What I have done thus far is:

1. Collect proposed username from `UITextView`
2. Pull the list of disallowed words from my `Firebase` database

I am returning the `snapshot` as its default return type, so, from here, I need to search said snapshot for any resemblance of the proposed username. How can I accomplish this? Here is some of the code I am using below:

```
 func nameFilter(input : String)-> Bool{
    var profanity : Bool  = false
    let dataRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    dataRef.child("Profanity").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value) { (snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        if(snap.exists()){
            if(snap.hasChild(input)){
                print("profanity")
                profanity = true
            }else{
         profanity = false
        }
        }else{
            print("null")
        }
    }
    return profanity
}
```

This didn't seem to work at all, so does anybody here have any ideas as to what I can try? This function always seems to return false no matter what I pass through it.

Comment: If you've stored it as one long string, see [How do I check if a string contains another string in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034043/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-swift).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen updated information, not saving it as string as that is actually impossible. It is being saved as a list of some sort. How can I search this?

Comment: Is `Profanity = false` supposed to be uppercased?

Comment: @Seth, no, added that in while typing the post. Has no part in the code right now

Comment: Can you add (a representative snippet of) the JSON at `Profanity` as text (no screenshot), which you can export from the Firebase Database console?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen not exactly sure that it would be appropriate to post something like that on here as it is filled with, well, a couple hundred lines of swears. I'll host the file on dropbox for you to take a look at.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen here the link for the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cud3rsmanpih84b/speedster-2c89f-export-5.json?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took care of this one myself, the code I used to accomplish this was:

```
func nameFilter(input : String)-> Bool{
    var profanity : Bool = true
    let dataRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    dataRef.child("Profanity").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value) { (snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        if(snap.exists()){
            if(snap.value! as! NSArray).containsObject(input){
                print("our ears!")
                profanity = true
            }else{
            profanity = false
        }


    }


}
    return profanity
}
```

Hopefully it is as useful for other people as it was to be.

Comment: Okay but how do you handle the case of a string like "assassin" or "class" vs "ass" .contains method will flag all of it