# Value of type 'string' has no member 'containsString'

Tags: ios, swift, string

I am new to iOS app developing.

I am implementing search bar programatically in swift 3 .

when I updated content for search controller I am getting this error.

> value of type 'string' has no member 'containsString'

on this line :

```
return  categoryMatch &&
 candy.name.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)
```

this is code :

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
            filteredCandies = candies.filter { candy in
                let categoryMatch = (scope == "All") || (candy.category == scope)
                return  categoryMatch && candy.name.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)
            }

            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Comment: where you get error?

Comment: If you use Swift 3, using `yourString.contains()` instead.

Comment: Which version of Swift are you talking about?. Please add the information in the question or use appropriate tags. If it's Swift 3 you will get much more errors in this code.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034043/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-swift

Comment: Read https://swift.org/migration-guide/, don't stay locked in your previous knowledge of Swift. You *have* to keep yourself updated, Swift evolves a lot and often.

Comment: I am using swift 3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using Swift 3 then change this line

```
return categoryMatch && candy.name.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)
```

to

```
return categoryMatch && candy.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
```

Comment: replacing lowercasestrings with lowercased() worked. thanks

Comment: **.lowercased()**