# How can I use swift to read through and identify?

Tags: swift

If I am using swift, how can I get my program to read through a string of letters to identify something? For example, lets say `var aa = "Apple"`. If I have this string of letters: `"aghdbgkldhgaabdfhjk"`, what code can I use for the program to read through it, identify `"aa"`, and print "apple"? I appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: This is very confusing. Can you please try to clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, sorry it does seem confusing the way I worded it. So lets say a user types a random series of letters. If this series of letters has two "a" right after one another, such as "aa" within that series of letters, I want the console to print "apple". Almost as if this program is reading through the series of letters and identifying "aa". Is this possible?

Comment: But what is mapping "aa" to "apple"? How does your app know to treat "aa" special as opposed to any other letters in the string the user types?

Comment: Yea that is what I am trying to figure out. Basically if a user types in a series of letters, presses a button, I want a new view controller to come up saying apple. Basically decoding and identifying "apple" within that series of letters. I was wondering if I could create a variable such as var aa = "apple". I am semi-new to swift and was wondering if there was some type of function within swift that can do this; Read through the letters and look for the match "aa".

Comment: You could create a dictionary that maps "aa" to "apple". You certainly wouldn't do anything based on variable names.

Comment: Ok, great! Thank you

Comment: String has a method name **contains**. Maybe it can help you

Answer (score 1):

you can check if your String contains "aa" in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24161872/2621857) 
then return 'Apple'

e.g:

```
var string = "aghdbgkldhgaabdfhjk"

if string.range(of: "aa", options: String.CompareOptions.diacriticInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil {
    print("apple")
}
```