# I have problem with comparing Strings in Swift

Tags: swift, string, if-statement, compare

I want to check a String to see if it contains a single letter. Here's the code:

```
func CheckLetter(letter:String,word:String) -> String{

    var checkFlag = false
    var tempWord = [""]

    for n in 0...(word.count-1){
        if tempWord[n] == letter[0]{

        }
    }

}
```

And the error is:
**'subscript(_:)' is unavailable: cannot subscript String with an Int, use a String.Index instead.**

Comment: This is not the error you are getting. You are getting that `"Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'Character'"`. The error you are describing will show if you fix the binary operator error. What is your goal? Are you trying to check if a string contains a character?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034043/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-swift

Comment: FYI, method and variable names should be lowercase. Only class names are uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [Swift String Cheat Sheet, by Keith Harrison](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-string-cheat-sheet/)

You can use:

```
func checkLetter(letter: String, word: String) -> String {

    return word.contains(letter).description
}
```

Comment: You answer is the closest one but there is something I forgot to tell, that if the word contains the letter, I want to know what is the index of that letter?

Comment: @SinaSB I added a link to an article you will find useful.

Answer (score 0):

try this !!!

```
func CheckLetter(letter:String,word:String) -> Bool{
        var checkFlag = false
        if word.contains(letter) {
            checkFlag = true
        }
        return checkFlag
    }
```