# Match part of a string with regex

Tags: swift, regex

I have two arrays of strings and I want to check if a string of `array a` matches a string from `array b`. Those strings are phone numbers that might come in different formats. For example:

Array a might have a phone number with prefix like so `+44123123123` or `0044123123123`

Array b have a standard format without prefixes like so `123123123`

So I'm looking for a regex that can match a part of a string like `+44123123123` with `123123123`

Btw I'm using Swift but I don't think there's a native way to do it (at least a more straightforward solution)

**EDIT**

I decided to reactivate the question after experimenting with the library @Larme mentioned because of inconsistent results.

I'd prefer a simper solution as I've stated earlier.

**SOLUTION**

Thanks guys for the responses. I saw many comments saying that Regex is not the right solution for this problem. And this is partly true. It could be true (or false) depending on my current setup/architecture ( which thinking about it now I realise that I should've explained better).
So I ended up using the native solution (hasSuffix/contains) but to do that I had to do some refactoring on the way the entire flow was structured. In the end I think it was the least complicated solution and more performant of the two. I'll give the bounty to @Alexey Inkin for being the first to mention the native solution and the right answer to @Ωmega for providing a more complete solution.

Comment: Not tested, but https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit seems interesting. I'd format all your numbers into the same style, and compare.

Comment: @Larme Yeah I already use it but their regex matches specific numbers with specific prefixes from different regions (and not always without errors). So you can imagine it takes a while to do all the necessary checks. I'm looking for a faster solution (by excluding prefixes altogether from the checks)

Comment: @Larme Sorry I just re-read the comment. I didn't think of using their formatters. That might do the trick. I'll have a look. Thanks

Comment: @Larme yep I can parse the number and get only the "national number" which is basically the number without the prefix

Comment: If you just want to see if it matches, why not just use index of or string contains kind of methods. Is there any other requirement too?

Comment: have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034043/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-another-string-in-swift

Comment: that'll be a long regex-mask to extract these numbers,

Comment: The solution to your problem is normalization, not Regex. If you need to compare two phone numbers you bring them both into normalized form and compare those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you do not mention requirements to prefixes, the simplest solution is to check if string in `a` ends with a string in `b`. For this, take a look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1541149-hassuffix

Then, if you have to check if the prefix belongs to a country, you may replace `^00` with `+` and then run a whitelist check against known prefixes. And the prefix itself can be obtained as a substring by cutting `b`'s length of characters. Not really a regex's job.

Answer (score 1):

I believe **regex** is not the right approach for this task.

Instead, you should do something like this:

```
var c : [String] = b.filter ({ (short : String) -> Bool in
  var result = false
  for full in a {
    result = result || full.hasSuffix(short)
  }
  return result
})
```

Check [this demo](https://www.ideone.com/kAZKBS).

---

...or similar solution like this:

```
var c : [String] = b.filter ({ (short : String) -> Bool in
  for full in a {
    if full.hasSuffix(short) { return true }
  }
  return false
})
```

Check [this demo](https://www.ideone.com/Uns9dJ).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Alexey Inkin that this can also nicely be solved without regex. If you really want a regex, you can try something like the following:

```
(?:(\+|00)(93|355|213|1684|376))?(\d+)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Add here all your expected country prefixes (see below)
^^^                            ^^ Match a country prefix if it exists but don't give it a group number
   ^^^^^^^ Match the "prefix-prefix" (+ or 00)
                                 ^^^^ Match the local phone number
```

Unfortunatly with this regex, you have to provide all the expected country prefixes. But you can surely get this list online, e.g. here: https://www.countrycode.org

With this regex above you will get the local phone number in matching group 3 (and the "prefix-prefix" in group 1 and the country code in group 2).